# NSUrlSessionTaskDelegate DidSendBodyData totalBytesSent inaccurate

Tags: ios, xamarin, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

NSUrlSessionTaskDelegate DidSendBodyData totalBytesSent seems to indicate that upload progress is being reported out of order.
I created a simple test with a single upload, and logged the value of totalBytesSent every time it was called.

For example,
totalBytesSent 3571712
totalBytesSent 3637248
totalBytesSent 3604480
totalBytesSent 3670016

I am seeing this happen around 1-3 times for a 5 MB file. I was wondering if anyone else could confirm this is a known issue, and I cannot rely on these being in the correct order.

Delegate:

```
    // For use with NSUrlSession that is configured for HttpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1
    public class TestUploadDelegate : NSUrlSessionTaskDelegate
    {
        public override void DidSendBodyData(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionTask task, long bytesSent, long totalBytesSent, long totalBytesExpectedToSend)
        {
             Console.WriteLine($"totalBytesSent {totalBytesSent}");
        }
    }
```

NSUrlSession creation:

```
    public NSUrlSession GetFileHostUrlSession()
    {
        if (this.fileHostUrlSession == null)
        {
            using var configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration(FileHostSessionIdentifier);
            configuration.AllowsCellularAccess = true;
            configuration.WaitsForConnectivity = true;
            configuration.ShouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = true;
            configuration.SessionSendsLaunchEvents = true;
            configuration.Discretionary = false;
            configuration.HttpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1; // Set to 1 for testing
            this.fileHostUrlSession = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(configuration, new TestUploadDelegate() as INSUrlSessionDelegate, new NSOperationQueue());
        }
        return this.fileHostUrlSession;
    }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: When you created the session, did you provide a delegate queue, and if so, is its underlyingQueue a serial queue?

Comment: When creating the NSUrlSession, I'm passing in a new NSOperationQueue. I will have to do some more research later if this doesn't answer your question. I added more sample code.

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: NSOperationQueue is concurrent by default, so order of callbacks is not guaranteed.  That's probably the problem.